# Integrate phone book in to my Android application

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my application I need to integrate android phone book and display the name of the contact while having the email with it. So when I select some of the contacts I need to return their respective email addresses. How can I do this ? Resources in Android doc didn't help me on this.
Can Some one please lead me to a example or any clue ? Thanks in Advance !